# Multithreading and async execution with ib_insync

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, coroutine, interactive-brokers

I am facing a perplexing problem when implementing multi-threading with ib_insync. My knowledge of both multithreading and asynchronous programming is surely insufficient to solve this.
Interestingly, the roadblock is only with the ib.sleep command and other functions seem to be working just fine.

Below are two scenarios - one without multi-threading and one with. Without multi-threading everything works fine, but when multi-threading is used to run parallelly, I get the following warning and the code stops.

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
```

What am I missing? I understand ib.sleep is a coroutine and needs to be awaited within an async function, but I do not understand how it works when called directly but only fails within a thread.
What is the best way to implement this correctly?

```
from ib_insync import * 
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor 
import random 
import nest_asyncio 
nest_asyncio.apply()
    
# Define IB object 
ib = IB()
    
# Connect to IB 
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=131)
    
# Define sample function with ib.sleep 
def sample_function(sleep_time):
    print('Sleeping now') 
    ib.sleep(sleep_time)
    print('Sleep completed!')
    
# Call function directly - works fine
sample_function()
    
# Run multiple threads and call function within each thread - RunTimeWarning and stops
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) 
executor.submit(sample_function, random.randint(1,20)) 
executor.submit(sample_function, random.randint(1,20))
```

Edit: The use case I am trying to solve for is to call a function parallelly with different parameters. Edited the sample code above accordingly. The catch here is ib_insync is an asynchronous implementation based on asyncio, so running multiple threads fails.

Comment: I very much doubt that it "works fine" when called from the main thread. Is there any actual delay between the two "Sleeping" messages? If not, then it doesn't work in either case, it just happens that in the main thread the warning is not shown. RuntimeWarning on non-awaited coroutines is provided on a best-effort basis and there's no guarantee that it will be emitted in all circumstances. Unless you know what you're doing, you shouldn't be mixing threads and asyncio. If you describe what you attempted to achieve with the threads, we might be able to help you to do the same with asyncio.

Comment: I am basically trying to call a function with different parameters parallelly. There is only one parameter for the function which is the company ticker, so idea is each thread is for one company ticker. The sample I shared in the description can be thought of as a proxy where I want to run the sleep function multiple times in parallel with different sleep times... Will appreciate inputs on how to implement this with asyncio only.

Comment: You can use `await asyncio.gather(coro1(param), coro2(param), ...)` to start multiple coroutines in parallel. Please edit the question to include the information about your use case.

Comment: Just did, thanks! If you wanted to add an answer, I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: Good to hear, I've now submitted an answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer. I was hoping for something more specific though. Given the sample function in the description, how would this be implemented?

Comment: I understood your previous comment to mean that my comment was enough for you to go by and that you'd accept it reworded as an answer. Given that we don't know your background, it's hard to tell what kind of a more specific answer you require. Have you tried to follow an [asyncio tutorial](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/)?

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't work fine in either case, it just happens that in the main thread the warning is not shown. `RuntimeWarning` on non-awaited coroutines is provided on a best-effort basis without a guarantee that it will be emitted in all circumstances.

To fix the issue, you should avoid mixing threads and asyncio in the first place. For example, if you need to run several coroutines in parallel, you can spawn them as tasks using `asyncio.crate_task`, and then await some or all of them. Or you can use the `asyncio.gather` utility function which does it for you:

```
result1, result2, ... = await asyncio.gather(coro1(), coro2(), ...)
```