# How can ib_insync reqHistoricalDataAsync work with Asyncio?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-multithreading

```
import asyncio
import ib_insync as ibi
import symbol_list
import time

start = time.perf_counter()
stocklist = symbol_list.test
endDateTime = '20190328 09:30:00'
durationStr='1 D'
dataDirectory = './data/tmp'

class App:

    async def run(self):
        self.ib = ibi.IB()
        with await self.ib.connectAsync():
            contracts = [
                ibi.Stock(symbol, 'SMART', 'USD')
                for symbol in ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'AMD', 'INTC']]
            for contract in contracts:
                # self.ib.reqMktData(contract)
                bars = await self.ib.reqHistoricalDataAsync(contract, 
                endDateTime=endDateTime, durationStr=durationStr,
                barSizeSetting='5 mins', whatToShow='MIDPOINT', useRTH=True)
                df = ibi.util.df(bars)
                df.to_csv(f"{dataDirectory}/{contract.symbol}.csv")


            async for tickers in self.ib.pendingTickersEvent:
                for ticker in tickers:
                    print(ticker)

    def stop(self):
        self.ib.disconnect()


app = App()
try:
    asyncio.run(app.run())
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    app.stop()

endtime = (time.perf_counter() - start)/60
print(f"Process time: {endtime:,.2f} minutes")
```

Please help. I modified the example code from [async-streaming-example](https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/recipes.html#async-streaming-ticks). I didn't get any error message, but it just runs without giving me the shell prompt.  And this code should only take less than a minute, if it runs properly. Essentially, instead of reqMktData, I want to use reqHistoricalDataAsync to get historical data, asynchronously.  I've also looked at [async execution with ib_insync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013115/multithreading-and-async-execution-with-ib-insync), but I wasn't able to get that technique to work, either.  Could you show me what I'm doing wrong? I welcome any async solutions. Thank you.